# "Land" on the pointer?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Consider the following spinning (spinner?) wheel:

[image]

The wheel spins. When it stops, an option (A, B, or C) *lands on* the pointer (dark gray).

Is *land on* the right phrase? I'm not very sure, because the options aren't on top of the pointer (it's the opposite). Is there a better phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have no problem with "lands on". We use the expression in various figurative ways, such as where responsibility sits (eg 'the job landed on me'). You may have heard this expression used after a roulette wheel has spun, however, in roulette there is actually a ball in the wheel that 'lands' on a number. That isn't the case with your wheel.

As there is nothing actually 'landing', you might find "it *stops* on..." more accurate and equally as idiomatic.

> The wheel (or pointer) stopped on grey.

Answer (score 2):

'The pointer lands on the option' [A, B or C].
I'd suspect this is simply a convention because, as you say, the pointer isn't moving, the wheel is.

You could say 'the option lands *under* the pointer', but a million game shows might argue that.

I'm sure game show hosts must have thought up a thousand alternatives to this stock phrasing, to try keep their show exciting.

'…and the winner is…'
'The wheel stops on…'
'Your next question/topic/subject is…' etc etc